# jqGrid v4, custom search form, how to?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

Im having some problems creating a custom search form for jqGrid, on the last version (v4).

I used before this method:

```
jQuery("#search-form").jqGrid(
    'filterGrid',
    '#grid', 
    options
);
```

However it does not work anymore, can someone give me an example on how to do this on version 4 of jqGrid?

Comment: Can you add more details? What is in your options variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the method `filterGrid` in jqGrid 4.0 you need include `grid.addons.js` from the `plugins` subdirectory.

How you can reed [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.8_to_4.0.0#the_following_methods_are_no_more_supported) the method `filterGrid` can be removed in the next major version of jqGrid. So I recommend you to consider to use some alternatives. You can create any list of custom form controls to allow user to define the grid filtering. To apply the filtering you need just to fill `filters` property of `postData` parameter and set `search` parameter of jqGrid to `true`. After that the call of trigger("reloadGrid") will apply the filtering. In the way you will be absolutely flexible and independent.

Below you can find some old answers where the idea with `filters` are implemented in different ways: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272850/is-there-an-api-in-jqgrid-to-add-advanced-filters-to-post-data/5273385#5273385), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981874/multiple-search-with-multiplefields-by-default/3981986#3981986), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973361/how-can-i-preserve-the-search-filters-in-jqgrid-on-page-reload/4977896#4977896), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688158/possible-to-make-jqgrid-search-box-stay-on-page/5689137#5689137) and so on.