# open search dialog box programmatically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to open a search dialog box programmatically in jqgrid.

as after submitting search the ajax request to the server I want to open it again but programmatically, so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One way of going about this is by forcing a `.click()` event on the search button.

I do it like this:

```
$("#search_list2").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the the `fbox_` prefix and the grid's id. Suppose your `jqGrid` has the id `myGridId` then the "Advanced Search" dialog will have `id="fbox_myGridId"`. This should then open the search box:

```
$("#fbox_myGridId").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can set this as an option when using the search grid of jqGrid:

```
$("#grid").searchGrid({ closeAfterSearch: false });
```

I found that here, which may relate to your question: [Possible to make jqGrid Search Box Stay on Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688158/possible-to-make-jqgrid-search-box-stay-on-page)

You can also set this as a default for the entire grid:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.search, { 
    closeAfterSearch: false
});
```

Comment: its keeping the dialogbox open even when i load the page , is it possible to close once i click on find ?

Comment: It seems that making it a default setting is what is causing it to be open all the time perhaps?